# Is it possible to access objects from another class without parameters

Tags: java, class, object, parameters

Is it possible to access an object created in one class from another class without using parameters/arguments?

For example:

```java
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Two make = new Two(); // Object I created.
    make.ham();
  }
}
class Two {
  public void ham() {
    System.out.println("Ham.");
  }
}
class Three {
  public static void accessObject() {
    // Can I access the object make here without parameters?
  }
}
```

Comment: What you mean "without the use of parameters?"

Comment: Because I know how to do this with parameters. But I want to do it without parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood is that you want to access to `make` object, created inside Main class **(Two make = new Two());**. And yes, it's possible to do it.
You have to create your variable `make` as global and static (and it's recommended be public or protected, in case you have your classes in separate files).
So, inside your Main class, you will have to do something like:

```
public class Main {
    
  public static Two make;
    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    make  = new Two(); // Object I created.
    make.ham();
    
    Three.accessObject();
  }
}
```

> As you can see, I created the `make` variable as **static** and **global**. This is necessary because your main method is static, and it's global to be able to be recognized by other classes. And to can call to `accessObject` method, I did it with the class name (because that method is static)(`Three.accessObject();`)

And finally inside your Three class, in the `accessObject` method it's necessary call to the static variable `make` from Main class:

```
class Three {
  public static void accessObject() {
    System.out.println("using make object from Main class in Three class...");
    Main.make.ham();
  }
}
```

> As you can see now, I called the variable `make` with the name class `Main` because it's static, and finally, you will be able to call the `ham` method by this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could you inheritance to solve your problem. For example, you would write:

```
class Three extends Two {
    public static void accessObject() {
        // You can now access the "Two" object since you have now made 
        // Three a subclass of Two.
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you wanted to say, change the implementation of the `ham()` method, you could do something like this:

```
class Two {
    public void ham() {
        System.out.println("Ham.");
    }
}

class Three extends Two {
    @Override
    public void ham() {
        System.out.println("I'm inside ham, but inside the Three class.);
    }
}
```

Comment: So how can I use it? Can you give an example? I get the error "symbol not found".

Comment: Sorry, what I want is to be able to access and use the object `make` inside class `Three`.

Comment: Yes, you can do that using inheritance.